# session not working in live site and works in localhost

Tags: php, session, zen-cart

I am working on Zen Cart.My web site involves shopping and billing for which maintaining session is very important.All the steps work correctly until I make the payment.After i submit for the payment it always fails.As I checked the session data gets emptied.I cant understand why this happens as the same code is working perfectly on my localhost.It isnt the problem of the place of session_start.It is placed on the top.Can it be the problem of header redirect?What can be the other possibilities for the error?

Comment: Code?! Did you checked for concrete errormessages? Have you debugged your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the files and find if somewhere session_destroy has mentioned and not commented.Start searching from the file after which the session is destroyed,obviously!!!

Answer (score 0):

try call session_start() in your first php file, or set in php.ini the session.auto_start option to true. make sure, session store path is accessable.
[php config](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)